# onClick keep stopping

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

```
public class MandarinPage extends AppCompatActivity {
Button b01,b02,b03;
VideoView Vv01;
MediaController mediaC;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mandarin_page);
    b01=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button01);
    b02=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button02);
    b03=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button03);

    Vv01=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
}

public void viedeplay(View v){
    String videopath = "android.resource://a0.besta_e_learning/"+R.raw.sample_video;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videopath); //URI stand for Uniform Resource Identifier
    Vv01.setVideoURI(uri);
    Vv01.setMediaController(mediaC);
    mediaC.setAnchorView(Vv01);
    Vv01.start();
}
```

[when i clicked my play button my emulator show this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6A8W.png)

can someone please help me with this ? any error there? when i click the button to play my video it show app keep stopping i got no idea which part of it went wrong.

Here the errors.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: a0.besta_e_learning, PID: 7198
>                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.MediaController.setAnchorView(android.view.View)' on a
>   null object reference
>                         at a0.besta_e_learning.MandarinPage.viedeplay(MandarinPage.java:32)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: please post errors

Comment: yeah...done....

Comment: please post layout for the onClick part

Comment: have you included this ?   `android:onClick="viedeplay" `

Comment: i using this method                                                                        
String videopath = "android.resource://a0.besta_e_learning/"+R.raw.sample_video;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(videopath); //URI stand for Uniform Resource Identifier
        Vv01.setVideoURI(uri);
        Vv01.setMediaController(mediaC);
        mediaC.setAnchorView(Vv01);
        Vv01.start();                                                                                 to play video so i couldn't use onClick.

Comment: what is this line `MandarinPage.java:32`

Comment: some one told me need to delete the (Main Activity) in onClick function but i tried still doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnJoe its another layer.

Comment: Error pointed to `MandarinPage.java:32`. Please show code for this line

Comment: @JohnJoe         mediaC.setAnchorView(Vv01);

Comment: I think  you don't have id `videoView ` in `R.layout.activity_mandarin_page`

Comment: VideoView Vv01;  Vv01=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView); i already declare all the variables.

Comment: maybe you miss to add the id in your layout

Comment: Example ---->  `<VideoView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/videoView"></VideoView>`

Comment: checked. Nothing wrong there.

Comment: then add this in onCreate method  `mediaC = new MediaController(this);`

Comment: @JohnJoe Its work. Thank you so much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think error is in this line ..Try to write the video extension of the video

```
String videopath = 
"android.resource://a0.besta_e_learning/"+R.raw.sample_video.mp4;
```

OR

```
 String videopath = 
 "android.resource://a0.besta_e_learning/"+R.raw.sample_video.3gp;
```

Comment: video doesn't matter i guess, it show keep stopping not can't play video.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it may help

```
MediaController mediaC = new MediaController(this);

Vv01.setMediaController(mediaC);
```